# Laravel passing an array to blade

Tags: variables, laravel, laravel-blade

Trying to use this,

```
return View::make('products.tables')->with('json', $json);
```

but get an Array to string conversion error.

json array

```
$json = array (
    "item1" => "no1",
    "item2" => "no2",
    "item3" => "no3",
    );
```

Comment: The error is probably happening somewhere else. Can you please post the rest of your code?

Comment: Could you provide structure of the `$json` variable?

Comment: How are you trying to output this in your view?

Comment: I'm guessing you have `{{ $json }}` in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that in your view you are calling array items wrong way.

It should be like this:

```
$json->item1
```

Or:

```
@foreach($json as $item)
    {{ $item }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$json = array (
    "item1" => "no1",
    "item2" => "no2",
    "item3" => "no3",
);

$data = array (
'json' => $json
);

return View::make('products.tables')->with($data)
```

and then, in your view:

```
@foreach($json as $item)
    {{ $item }}
@endforeach
```

This should work.